# Best approach to run a Spring Batch job

Tags: spring-boot, spring-batch, spring-rest

I have a requirement where I have to call a spring batch job from a rest endpoint. We are using an API which has all the boilerplate code for running a job and it also adds an endpoint to our service and upon calling that endpoint it will run the requested job. I have attached a snip of that endpoint.

[image]

Please suggest a best approach to run the job from another rest endpoint within the same service should I call /Jobs endpoint or should I implement the logic of running the required job? TIA.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no best approaches, it depends on the use case. I would not make REST endpoints call each others, I think it would be simpler to inject the `JobLauncher` in your controller and call your job accordingly. You can find more details and a code example in the reference documentation here: [Running Jobs from within a Web Container](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/docs/4.3.x/reference/html/job.html#runningJobsFromWebContainer).